# unable to use mysql in mariadb server with no clear reason

Tags: kali-linux, mysql, mariadb

in case i just type mysql -u root -p and enter my password i enter to my database but now
i still get one message every time i say mysql and any option like this output

```
root@Dodge:~# mysql
Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status
root@Dodge:~# mysql -u root
Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status
root@Dodge:~# mysql -u root -p
Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status
```

this message mean the service not running right ? but when i run status i get the services is active

```
root@Dodge:~# systemctl status mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.9 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-05-13 10:33:27 EET; 16min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 9337)
     Memory: 0B
        CPU: 0
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
root@Dodge:~# systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.9 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-05-13 10:33:27 EET; 16min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 9337)
     Memory: 0B
        CPU: 0
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
```

is active so why still give me

Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status

i was try to uninstall every thin and re install it
and install with secure & update my system - i use kali-linux Based on debian for many years
and there's no problem with it .

**Edit**

When i run mysql status i get this logs in the bottom too

```
ay 13 11:15:37 Dodge mariadbd[14041]: 2021-05-13 11:15:37 3 [Warning] Access denied for user 'roo…rd: NO)
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge mariadbd[14041]: 2021-05-13 11:15:37 4 [Warning] Access denied for user 'roo…rd: NO)
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge /etc/mysql/debian-start[14065]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option…nored
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge /etc/mysql/debian-start[14065]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge /etc/mysql/debian-start[14065]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge /etc/mysql/debian-start[14065]: Version check failed. Got the following error …lient
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge /etc/mysql/debian-start[14065]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ro…: NO)
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge /etc/mysql/debian-start[14065]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge mariadbd[14041]: 2021-05-13 11:15:37 5 [Warning] Access denied for user 'roo…rd: NO)
May 13 11:15:37 Dodge debian-start[14078]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'local…d: NO)
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: You seem to either have a misconfigured PATH or the mysql client was replaced by something else. To investigate, find out which mysql you are actually calling. The shell built-in `type` and the command `which` help. You could also use the full pathname of the mysql client when running it.

Comment: Your problem is most likely a client, not a server problem. However, the service is *active* but *exited*. I wonder whether it is running.

Comment: i install **mariadb-client** now and same problem 
i use **which** to mysql and i get 1 result
**/etc/init.d//mysql**

Comment: so i use this command ?
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Comment: yes the problem is i add `export PATH="/etc/init.d/:$PATH"`  inside `.bashrc` but  ido that to run script direct with out `full path`

Comment: how do i mark the comment above  as right answer ?

Comment: I turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which mysql` returns `/etc/init.d/mysql`. This is so because `/etc/init.d` is in your PATH before `/usr/bin`, which has the effect that you execute `/etc/init.d/mysql` when typing `mysql`.

You need to ensure that the location of the mysql client comes before `/etc/init.d` in the PATH. Or remove `/etc/init.d` from the PATH; I don't see any reason why it's there. Also, to make this change permanent, you need to change the setting of PATH in your profile or bashrc file.

Should you have reasons not to change the PATH variable, you need to launch the mysql client by providing its full pathname: `/usr/bin/mysql`.